# Why am i getting errors in my code in android studio?

Tags: java, android, button, package, void

I am doing a customisation app where the user is buying personalised products. I am trying to do the basket page but it just isn't working. I have an error in the `Bundle BuyIntent = mservice.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,"Purchase text item","bGoa+V7g/yqD");` and also in the `skuDetails= mservice.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),"Purchase text item", querySku);`. It is saying cannot resolve method. Please can someone help, thank you.

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.ResponseCache;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver.Stub;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class Basket extends AppCompatActivity {
    Basket mservice;
    ServiceConnection connection;
    String purchase = "android.test.purchased";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basket);

        connection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

                mservice = null;
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
               Stub.asInterface(service);
            }};

            bindService(new Intent(
                    "com.example.emily.activity.414timber"),
                    connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Button purchaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
        purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
                skuList.add(purchase);
                Bundle querySku = new Bundle();
                querySku.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
                Bundle skuDetails;

                try {
                    skuDetails= mservice.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                            "Purchase text item", querySku);

                    int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                    if (response == 0){

                        ArrayList <String> responseList = skuDetails
                                .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                        for (String thisResponse : responseList){
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                            String sku = object.getString("productId");
                            String price = object.getString("price");
                            if (sku.equals(purchase)){
                                System.out.println("price " + price);
                                Bundle BuyIntent = mservice.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                        "Purchase text item",
                                        "bGoa+V7g/yqD");
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent= BuyIntent
                                        .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                                startIntentSenderForResult(
                                        pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),1001,
                                        new Intent(),Integer.valueOf(0),
                                        Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (RemoteException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == 1001 ){
            String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                    String sku = jo.getString(purchase);
                    Toast.makeText(
                            Basket.this,
                            "You have bought the" + sku
                                    + "Excellent choice, adventurer!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                }
            }
        }
   @Override
           public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            if (connection != null){
                unbindService(connection);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: skuDetails= mservice.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "Purchase text item", querySku); - cannot resolve method 'getSkuDetails(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.os.Bundle)'

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the declaration for getSkuDetails()?  From you error message it sounds like you may be expecting either a different number of arguments or different data types.

Comment: what is or where do I find the getSkuDetails() from?

Comment: It's part of your basket? 
Basket mservice;
 skuDetails= mservice.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                            "Purchase text item", querySku);

Comment: yeah but where do i get the declaration?

Comment: I just noticed that this is the basket class.  You are referencing the object within itself.  since you don't have the getSkuDetails method written, that would explain why you can't resolve it.  You need to implement that method.

Comment: I am new to android studio but the basket class is what i copied into the question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a service to handle this for you.  I can't tell you how to do that because I don't know exactly what you are trying to do or where your data comes from.  You need to work on your design and research how to do all this.  If you get stuck on something specific then that would make for a good question like your original.